# Meaning of $x^T A x$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms, positive-semidefinite

I've seen the term  $x^T A x$, where $A$ is a square and usually symmetric matrix, come up in a bunch of different areas of linear algebra. Places I've seen it include defining the Raleigh quotient, defining positive/negative semi-definite matrices, and in the derivation of PCA. I've also seen it sometimes referred to as describing a quadratic form.

Is there some general definition/ intuitive description of what $x^T A x$ means with respect to a vector and a matrix?

My sort of vague understanding is that it describes how a vector is changed under a linear transformation defined by $A$ (for example if $A$ causes x to rotate 90 $^\circ$ then $x^T A x = 0$) but I can't seem to come up with a more precise or insightful description of $x^T A x$, and I'm surprised how little I could find online considering how often I see this term come up.

Comment: Do you know what a bilinear form is?

Comment: No I don't. I will look into that thanks.

Comment: OK so I can see that you could describe $x^T A x$ as a bilinear map that takes a nxn matrix and a vector of size n to a real number but I'm still not sure how that illuminates the meaning of it.

Comment: In some sense, you can consider it the linear algebra analogue to group theory conjugation (that is, sending $h$ to $g^{-1}hg$ for $h, g$ elements of a group).

Comment: One example from physics might be the rotational energy: It can be written in the form of $E=\frac{1}{2} \omega^T I \omega$, where $\omega$ is the angular velocity vector and $I$ is the inertia matrix.

Comment: So the T is a transpose, because if A is an n by n matrix and x is a n by 1 vector, then how can you multiply Ax on the left by x?

Comment: yes T is a transpose

Comment: I know them as Real Quadratic Forms.

Comment: When $A $ is symmetric, this is used to give corresponding conic section equation $x^TAx=(Q^Tx)^TDQ^Tx=d $ in the most basic/simple form (wrt eifenvector basis).

Comment: So asking for the “meaning” of this is entirely contextually dependent. An interesting area where this might have a good geometric interpretation is the classification of conics.

Comment: If $A $ is positive for example, then this value is also positive. It $A $ is invertible, then it is non-zero for all non-zero $x $.

Comment: $A$ might as well be symmetric since the skew-symmetric part of $A$ contributes nothing to the value of $x^TAx$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$Ax$$ represents the vector $x$ after it has undergone the linear transform described by $A$ and

$$x^TAx$$ is the dot product of the original and the transformed vectors. This dot product is zero when the two vectors are orthogonal, and maximized/minimized when they are parallel/antiparallel.

If $x$ is an Eigenvector of $A$,

$$x^TAx=\lambda x^Tx=\lambda\|x\|^2.$$

More generally, $x$ is a linear combination of Eigenvectors $ue_1+ve_2+\cdots we_n$ and

$$x^TAx=\lambda_1u^2+\lambda_2v^2+\cdots\lambda_nw^2$$ is a canonical quadratic form. Depending on the signs of the lambdas, the equation $x^TAx=1$ describes an ellipsoid or some kind of hyperboloid.

Comment: In that last equation you wrote, are the $u^2$, $v^2$, $w^2$ the weights of each eigenvector in the linear combination, or do they represent the squared magnitudes of the eigenvectors?

Comment: If $A$ is real valued you need $A^T=A$ (A is symmetric) to give an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ of eigenvectors for $A$. If $A$ is complex valued you need $A^*=A$ ( A is Hermetian) to give an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$ of eigenvectors of $A$.  You're using $\{e_i\}$ are orthonormal in your expansion $$x^TAx=\lambda_1u^2+\lambda_2v^2+\cdots\lambda_nw^2$$

Comment: @person1: they are the wieights, i.e. the coordinates in the frame of the Eigenvectors.

Comment: @YvesDaoust doesn't the last part only holds if A is symmetric? (orthogonal eigenvectors)